# How do I export an HTML table to excel

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js, sheetjs

I am trying to export an HTML table into an excel file.
Because I am already using sheetjs for importing excel files, I have been trying to use it as well for exporting.
Searching the internet, it seems to be only possible together with filesaver.js.
Below is what I have been trying but without success.

```js
var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(tbl);
console.log(wb)

var blob = new Blob([tbl], {
    type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=charset=utf-8"
});
saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
}

td,
th {
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

th {
    background-color: #dce0e3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.11.6/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
            <td>Maria Anders</td>
            <td>Germany</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Centro comercial</td>
            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
            <td>Mexico</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
            <td>Austria</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Island Trading</td>
            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
            <td>UK</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Laughing Bacchus </td>
            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Magazzini Alimentari </td>
            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
            <td>Italy</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be after a scraper, there's one I found here, which might start you in the right direction:

http://analystcave.com/excel-scraping-html-regular-expression-continued/